# Bind Trouble Ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu, dns, bind

Following this link, I have been tring to bind youplus.biz 66.96.162.140(domain) to 192.169.218.8(hosting)

http://linuxconfig.org/linux-dns-server-bind-configuration

here is my stuff

File: db.youplus.biz

```
;
; BIND data file for youplus.biz
;
$TTL    3h
@       IN      SOA     NS1.DOMAIN.COM. youplus.biz. (
                          1        ; Serial
                          3h       ; Refresh after 3 hours
                          1h       ; Retry after 1 hour
                          1w       ; Expire after 1 week
                          1h )     ; Negative caching TTL of 1 day
;
@       IN      NS      NS1.DOMAIN.COM.
@       IN      NS      NS2.DOMAIN.COM.

youplus.    IN      MX      30      mx.youplus.biz.
youplus.    IN      A   192.169.218.8
;ns1                     IN      A       NS1.DOMAIN.COM.
;ns2                     IN      A       NS2.DOMAIN.COM.
www 

                IN      CNAME   youplus.biz.
```

File: db.218.169.192

```
; BIND reverse data file for 218.169.192.in-addr.arpa
;
$TTL    604800
218.169.192.in-addr.arpa.      IN      SOA     NS1.DOMAIN.COM. youplus.biz. (
                          1         ; Serial
                          3h       ; Refresh after 3 hours
                          1h       ; Retry after 1 hour
                          1w       ; Expire after 1 week
                          1h )     ; Negative caching TTL of 1 day
;
218.169.192.in-addr.arpa.       IN      NS      NS1.DOMAIN.COM.
218.169.192.in-addr.arpa.       IN      NS      NS2.DOMAIN.COM.


8.218.169.192.in-addr.arpa.   IN      PTR     youplus.biz.
```

When I do : **$named-checkzone 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa /etc/bind/zones/master/db.218.169.192**

I get:

```
/etc/bind/zones/master/db.218.169.192:5: ignoring out-of-zone data (218.169.192.in-addr.arpa)
/etc/bind/zones/master/db.218.169.192:12: ignoring out-of-zone data (218.169.192.in-addr.arpa)
/etc/bind/zones/master/db.218.169.192:13: ignoring out-of-zone data (218.169.192.in-addr.arpa)
/etc/bind/zones/master/db.218.169.192:16: ignoring out-of-zone data (8.218.169.192.in-addr.arpa)
zone 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: has 0 SOA records
zone 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: has no NS records
zone 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

The strange thing is when I do

**dig @192.169.218.8 www.youplus.biz**
and
**ping youplus.biz**

form within the server I get

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> @192.169.218.8 www.youplus.biz
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10575
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.youplus.biz.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.youplus.biz.    10800   IN  CNAME   youplus.biz.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
youplus.biz.        3600    IN  SOA NS1.DOMAIN.COM. youplus.biz. 1 10800 3600 604800 3600

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.169.218.8#53(192.169.218.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 10 13:00:21 MST 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 108
```

and

```
root@youplus:/etc/bind/zones/master# ping youplus.biz 
PING youplus.biz (192.169.218.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from youplus.biz (192.169.218.8): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms
64 bytes from youplus.biz (192.169.218.8): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
64 bytes from youplus.biz (192.169.218.8): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
```

But outside the server I get

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @192.169.218.8 www.youplus.biz
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36912
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.youplus.biz.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.youplus.biz.    10800   IN  CNAME   youplus.biz.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
youplus.biz.        3600    IN  SOA NS1.DOMAIN.COM. youplus.biz. 1 10800 3600 604800 3600

;; Query time: 35 msec
;; SERVER: 192.169.218.8#53(192.169.218.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 10 12:44:28 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 97
```

and

```
id2:~ tithos$ ping youplus.biz
PING youplus.biz (66.96.162.140): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 66.96.162.140: icmp_seq=0 ttl=240 time=88.023 ms
64 bytes from 66.96.162.140: icmp_seq=1 ttl=240 time=88.015 ms
64 bytes from 66.96.162.140: icmp_seq=2 ttl=240 time=93.105 ms
64 bytes from 66.96.162.140: icmp_seq=3 ttl=240 time=88.458 ms
64 bytes from 66.96.162.140: icmp_seq=4 ttl=240 time=99.905 ms
64 bytes from 66.96.162.140: icmp_seq=5 ttl=240 time=87.863 ms
```

Any thoughts?  This is driving me up the wall

Answer (score 0):

Typo 1: 218.**169**.192.in-addr.arpa. vs 218.**168**.192.in-addr.arpa

Typo 2: stray dot after youplus in "youplus. IN A" and "youplus. IN MX"

For `ping` and other commands that use the system resolver and not resolve themselves (like `host` and `dig` do), you need to check /etc/resolv.conf, /etc/hosts etc., to get to the bottom of how names are resolved.

For ping on the host itself, you have youplus.biz in /etc/hosts, so your DNS server is not consulted at all. For ping on the other host, it again is not configured in your /etc/resolv.conf to use your own DNS server, but uses real name servers and resolves to a placeholder web page probably set up by whoever you registered the name with.

Comment: my /etc/hosts127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
192.169.218.8   youplus.biz youplus

# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
192.169.218.8 youplus.biz youplus

Answer (score 0):

See the domain's whois data:

```
$ whois youplus.biz |grep 'Name Server'
Name Server:                                 NS77.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
Name Server:                                 NS78.DOMAINCONTROL.COM
```

It happens this way: 
When you do

```
dig @192.169.218.8 www.youplus.biz
```

you force dig to go to 192.169.218.8 nameserver and ask for domain www.youplus.biz
Wnen you `ping youplus.biz` from the server it uses DNS server from `/etc/resolv.conf`. I'm sure that you have 127.0.0.1 there as you've installed bind on that server.

When you do ping youplus.biz *not* from the server ping uses resolver from the local system. The resolver from your local system only knows DNS server for domain youplus.biz which is stated in whois data (really simplified version, but you can always see the DNS server which will be used in whois data)

So you need to change DNS servers for domain youplus.biz to 192.169.218.8 instead of the current NS77.DOMAINCONTROL.COM/NS78.DOMAINCONTROL.COM. It is usually done via domain registrar's control panel.